# How to create a json object with repeating column value

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my query output:

```
        Month   SARType Count
        ---------------------------
        April   Data Protection Breach  2
        April   Miscellaneous - Employee Matters/Fraud  1
        April   Miscellaneous - Information Security    2
        April   Miscellaneous - Unusual Calls/Correspondence    1
        April   Theft - Damage/Theft/Lost Company Property  1
        March   Code of Conduct - Disclosure of Password    1
        March   Data Protection Breach  2
        March   Information Security - Phishing/Spear Phishing  1
        March   Miscellaneous - Employee Matters/Fraud  2
        March   Miscellaneous - Information Security    10
        March   Miscellaneous - Unusual Calls/Correspondence    5
```

I need to create a json in following style for amcharts:

```
var chartData = [{
    month: "April",
    Data Protection Breach: 2,
    Miscellaneous - Employee Matters/Fraud: 1,
    Miscellaneous - Information Security: 2,
    Miscellaneous - Unusual Calls/Correspondence: 1},
   {
    month: "March",
    Data Protection Breach: 2,
    Miscellaneous - Employee Matters/Fraud: 1,
    Miscellaneous - Information Security: 2,
    Miscellaneous - Unusual Calls/Correspondence: 1}];
```

I don't know how to exclude the repeating month column from the query result and keep adding the corresponding rows as a parameter to the same json object. I am using string builder to create a json in my MVC application. Any help will be highly appreciable!

Comment: Group by `Month` then create dictionary/name-value pairs from rows insode the group

Comment: I have done group by in my query, how to do it in the code?

Comment: With LINQ Expression, you can use groupby

Comment: Show which kind of data types you are using `DataTable` or collections?

Comment: @Fabio I am using DataTable as input to my function. There I am using StringBuilder to iterate the table and create a JSON which I am passing back to my chart method.

Comment: @user3801869 could you explain in detail grouping by can help me achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

With code below you should get collection of dictionaries for every month, where every dictionary have keys as values of `SARType` and values as values of `Count`

```cs
var data = 
    yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Month"))
                 .Select(group => 
                 {
                     var temp = new Dictionary<string, object>
                     {
                         { "month", group.Key }
                     }

                     foreach(var row in group)
                     {
                         temp.Add(row.Field<string>("SARType"), row.Field<int>("Count"));
                     }

                     return temp;
                 });

serializedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```